# Using gSoap in Qt/Windows

Tags: qt, mingw, gsoap

I followed [the steps](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html) on gSoap's page and tried to run the example code in Qt/Windows with Mingw32 Compiler. However, I can't add lgsoap++ to linker, as stated in the documentation, since it is not in [the source package](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=52781)

> To complete the build, compile and
>   link the generated soapC.cpp,
>   soapcalcProxy.cpp, and the run-time
>   gSOAP engine -lgsoap++  (or use source
>   stdsoap2.cpp in case libgsoap++.a is
>   not installed) with your code.

Then I tried adding stdsoap2.cpp to SOURCES and [this is the compile output](http://pastebin.com/FFe03FZT) as a result. So my question is how I will run this example code snippet in Qt with Mingw32 compiler or how I will generate that lgsoap++. Followings are my pro and source files:

```
QT -= gui
TARGET = SoapCalc
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp \
    ../Console/gsoap/stdsoap2.cpp
OTHER_FILES += ../../../../../gsoap/gsoap-2.7/gsoap/calc.nsmap
HEADERS += ../../../../../gsoap/gsoap-2.7/gsoap/soapcalcProxy.h


#include"C:/gsoap/gsoap-2.7/gsoap/soapcalcProxy.h"
#include"C:/gsoap/gsoap-2.7/gsoap/calc.nsmap"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    calcProxy service;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I have resolved it.
 Follow the [guidelines](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc1.1) on the gSoap's page. Add the following files to your project: generated *.cpp, *.h, *.nsmap, service definition file - the name of which you type on command line e.g. calc.h in the guideline - and stdsoap2.h/cpp files in the gsoap directory of the downloaded zip file. After including proxy file -e.g. soapcalcProxy.h - and *.nsmap to your main file there remains one thing that 
I forgot to realize before:

add  **LIBS += C:\MinGW\lib\libws2_32.a** to your *.pro file. libws32_a is the current version of the deprecated libwsock32.a file.