# What direction should I follow to add webservice functionalities to my application?

Tags: c++, matlab, soap, ssl

I have a problem, and I know there are many ways to solve it. I hope you can help me chose the fittest.

I am developping an application mainly using Matlab, and I try to gradually shift some of its functionalities to c++. I develop on windows, for windows.

I am quite experienced in these two programming languages, but I know nothing of web development.

I want to add some functionalities to this application that will use some webservices hosted on a server protected by ssl.

I am alone on this project, but I can spend some time learning new stuff if need be.

I would like to know what tools you think I should better use for this task ?

So far, I have tried and failed the following approach :

- calling the webservice directly from Matlab. I have added the self-signed ssl certificate to every truststore I could find on my computer, but I keep getting an error telling me that the certificate is not valid.
- calling the webservice using gSoap and c++. For this, I need to rebuild the gSoap binaries with ssl capabilities. I tried too do so using visual studio and mingw/gcc but did not succeed, and I could not find any help online.

I have the feeling after a few hours/days browsing and looking for solution that the tools I try to use are not the most used and therefore not the best documented (and therefore not the best suited for a rookie), so what is your advice?

Comment: gSoap was my 1st thought when reading your question, especially if you'll need to integrate web-services as C++ clients. AFAIR it should be possible to use it along with SSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using gSoap from your C++ modules would be the best choice.

Information about using gSoap with SSL as client is available here: [Secure SOAP Clients with HTTPS/SSL](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc19.22)

A link about using gSoap for building a VS Application: [Creating a gSoap eBay Client Application with Visual C++ 2008](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30497/Creating-a-gSoap-eBay-Client-Application-with-Visu)

May be this helps for using gSoap with MinGW: [Using gSoap in Qt/Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795760/using-gsoap-in-qt-windows)

Comment: Well, thank you for your answers I will insist with gSoap then. I have asked a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15955418/how-to-compile-gsoap-with-ssl-enabled-on-windows) describing the issue I met when trying to build gSoap with SSL enabled using MinGW.